# Windows Server 2012 hide external HDD for non-admins

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, hard-drive, active-directory

I am setting up a server where people connect to via Remote Desktop. It uses AD DS and uses an external HDD with a share on it for people's data.

However when these people log on, aside from the mapped share they also see the HDD entry in File Explorer. I've taken away all rights from them so that the drive would not show up but it is still there.

Is there a way to hide it? Perhaps the $ at the back of the name or is that only for shares?

Elaboration:
[image]
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is this system actually actually a domain controller?  You mention ADDS.  Or do you have an actual Remote Desktop Services deployment?  Have you seen this KB?  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/231289

Comment: @Zoredache The server is a domain controller but all Remote Desktop sessions are not with the special role. Just standard. It uses Active Directory accounts to open a remote desktop session with the server. I will look into the KB you provided. I'll keep you posted.

Comment: You understand that using a DC for any kind of Remote Desktop sessions other than for administration is strongly discouraged?

Comment: Yes it is not for production. Just for messing around.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do is to remove the drive letter from the external HDD, in Disk Management or via diskpart.exe remove the drive letter and mount the partition to an empty NTFS folder instead.

Put the mount-folder somewhere deep in your file structure and ACLe it, name it, so a normal user wouldn't suspect anything.